# How to get shipping estimates for out of stock products?

Tags: shipping, out-of-stock

I have the shipping estimate widget on every product page, so that users can check the shipping price before adding them to cart. This works well for in-stock products, but not for out of stock.

Seems like Magento restricts out of stocks products via `$product->isSaleable()`.

Is there a way for out of stock products to get their shipping estimates?